# Is there any better way for changing the source code of a container instead of creating a new image?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

What is the best way to change the source code of my application running as Kubernetes pod without creating a new version of image so I can avoid time taken for pushing and pulling image from repository?

Comment: Well, doing this you would loose many of the benefits containers bring.

Comment: If you are focused only for development, you might want to checkout Telepresence https://www.telepresence.io

Comment: As Henry mentioned you'd be losing the benefits of containers. The goal is to package your code and environment. A volume would do what you are asking I would not recommend using it as it is not its purpose

Comment: Ok. I understand. If we don't  have source code inside the image, the new pods in Deployment or Replication controller can't get the source code. Am I correct?

Comment: This is a very bad idea and can lead to confusion and something called configuration drift. You need to think of containers as immutable things. Read up on the terms cattle and pet. https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/653/what-is-the-definition-of-cattle-not-pets

Answer (score 0):

You may enter the container using bash if it installed on the image and modify it using -

```
docker exec -it <CONTAINERID> /bin/bash
```

However, this isn’t advisable solution. If your modifications succeed, you should update the Dockerfile accordingly or else you risk losing your work and ability to share it with others.

Answer (score 0):

Have the container pull from git on creation?

Setup CI/CD?

Comment: I don't understand your question. But, image is being built from the source code that is available in git hub.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to achieve a similar result is to leave the application source outside of the container and mount the application source folder in the container.

This is especially useful when developing web applications in environments such as PHP: your container is setup with your Apache/PHP stack and /var/www/html is configured to mount your local filesystem.

If you are using minikube, it already mounts a host folder within the minikube VM. You can find the exact paths mounted, depending on your setup, here:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/minikube/#mounted-host-folders

Putting it all together, this is what a nginx deployment would look like on kubernetes, mounting a local folder containing the web site being displayed:

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
 replicas: 1
  template: 
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.7.9
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /var/www/html/
          name: sources
          readOnly: true
      volumes:
      - name: sources
        hostPath:
          path: /Users/<username>/<source_folder>
          type: Directory
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally we have resolved the issue. Here, we changed our image repository from docker hub to aws ecr in the same region where we are running kubernetes cluster. Now, it is taking very lesstime for pushing/pulling images.

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely not recommended for production.

But if your intention is local development with kubernetes, take a look at these tools:

[**Telepresence**](https://www.telepresence.io/)

> Telepresence is an open source tool that lets you run a single service
>   locally, while connecting that service to a remote Kubernetes cluster.

**[Kubectl warp](https://kubedex.com/resource/kubectl-warp/)**

> Warp is a kubectl plugin that allows you to execute your local code
>   directly in Kubernetes **without slow image build process**.
>
> The `kubectl warp` command runs your command inside a container, the same
>   way as `kubectl run` does, but before executing the command, it
>   synchronizes all your files into the container.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be taken as process to create new images for each deployment. 
Few benefits:

- immutable images: no intervention in running instance this will ensure image run in any environment
- rollback: if you encounter issues in new version, rollback to previous version
- dependencies: new versions may have new dependencies